# Mouse button in ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, toolstrip

I have a context menu with a few items. One of the items has a submenu (or whatever it's called) with a few items (depends on what files it finds).

What I want to do is when I left click one of the sub-items I want one thing to happen, and when I right click I want another thing to happen.

My problem is that when I use the filesToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked, I don't get any MouseEventArgs in the parameter, so I can't find out which mouse button was used to click the item.

I tried adding it myself in the parameter but I get some error then.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? So I can find out what mouse button was used to click the sub-item (which is a ToolStripMenuItem)?

Thanks

edit: here is the code I use to create the sub items:

```
IPHostEntry ipE = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress[] IpA = ipE.AddressList;
for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
{
      if (!IpA[i].ToString().Contains(":"))
           cxItems.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(IpA[i].ToString()));
}
```

And for those items I want to be able to do different things depending on which mouse button I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu1");
        ToolStripMenuItem subMenuitem1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("SubMenu");
        item1.DropDownItems.Add(subMenuitem1);
        this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item1);
        subMenuitem1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(subMenuitem1_MouseDown);
        this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.button2,new Point(0,0));
    }

    void subMenuitem1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Button will determine which button was clicked.
        MessageBox.Show(e.Button.ToString());
    }
```

That should help get you started.

RE: You're edit:

The problem is, you're just saying new ToolStripMenuItem(IpA[i].ToString()) without keep a reference to it. Here's how you need to do it:

```
 IPHostEntry ipE = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress[] IpA = ipE.AddressList;
    for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
    {
          if (!IpA[i].ToString().Contains(":"))
          {
               ToolStripMenuItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(IpA[i].ToString());
               subItem.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(subItem_MouseDown);
               cxItems.Items.Add(subItem);
          }
    }

    void subMenuitem1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
          //get a reference to the menu that was clicked
          ToolStripMenuItem clickedMenu = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
          //e.Button will tell you which button was clicked.
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I'm creating the sub items at runtime or whatever you call it. Like it searches for some files and if it finds them it creates one item for each file. So I can't really do like in your example.

Comment: Post the code of how you're creating the sbuitems, and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks! There was only a small error with subItem.MouseClick, but i changed it to subItem.MouseDown instead. But it's working now so thank you very much! I'm marking this post as the correct answer.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I just fixed it in my answer. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get access to the sub MenuItem?  If so you can handle the MouseDown event on the sub item.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem optionToolStripMenuItem;
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem subitemToolStripMenuItem;
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem subItem2ToolStripMenuItem;

public void init()
{
    // 
    // optionToolStripMenuItem
    // 
    this.optionToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
    this.subitemToolStripMenuItem,
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem});
    this.optionToolStripMenuItem.Name = "optionToolStripMenuItem";
    this.optionToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
    this.optionToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Option";
    // 
    // subitemToolStripMenuItem
    // 
    this.subitemToolStripMenuItem.Name = "subitemToolStripMenuItem";
    this.subitemToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
    this.subitemToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Subitem";
    // 
    // subItem2ToolStripMenuItem
    // 
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "subItem2ToolStripMenuItem";
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "SubItem2";
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown);
    this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.subItem2ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
}

private bool wasRightClicked = false;
private void subItem2ToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        wasRightClicked = true;
}
```