# catch mouseClick and KeyDown event in ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, winforms

I have A menu Strip in MDI Parent Form in which cut, copy, paste Tool strip menu items are present. I want to catch keydown and mouseClick (Left) event in ToolStripMenuItem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse button in ToolStripMenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520573/mouse-button-in-toolstripmenuitem)

Comment: you can use keyPreview event of Form.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the items on the toolstrip, you need a listener. Like this:

```
AddHandler menu_item_logout.Click, AddressOf logout
```

Then you need a subroutine to handle the event like this:

```
Private Sub logout()
 ' do something here
End Sub
```

As for the keyboard, you need to listen for keystrokes and then handle those like this:

```
AddHandler first_name_box.KeyDown, AddressOf check_key
```

Then have a Subroutine to handle those:

```
Private Sub check_key(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        ' When the Enter key is pressed, trigger the event
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
            ' do something 
        End If
End Sub
```